# 403 FORBIDDEN use ajax to send post DJANGO

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I use Ajax for send in POST data to view of Django but I have this error : 403 FORBIDDEN.

Actually, I use @csrf_exempt but I'm affraid isn't the better idea...

My view :

```
@csrf_exempt
def myfic(request):
    if request.method == "POST" :
        competences = request.POST.get('theCompetences')
        print("competences : ",competences)
    ...
```

My code JS :

```
function envoie_post_competences(){
    $.post("http://localhost:8000/myfic",{theCompetences:"aaaaaaa",});
    return false;
}
```

What's the better solution ?

Thank you for your help !

---

So just i must add this code :

```
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

and my function JS not changed ?

```
function envoie_post_competences(){
    $.post("http://localhost:8000/myfic",{theCompetences:"aaaaaaa",});
    return false;
}
```

If yes, when I click on submit button, nothing is happening..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `X-CSRFToken` header, like shown in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: So juste I add the code in the documentation in my code js ?

Comment: That should work. If it doesn't, use a  debugger like FireBug to see what is actually happening during the AJAX request.